# Is there a definitive list of all possible labels or objects or tags for the Microsoft Cognitive Services Computer Vision API?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm building a web application using multiple APIs which are a part of the Microsoft cognitive Services bundle.

The API returns detected objects such as person, man, fly, kite, etc. I require a list of all possible objects that the API is capable of detecting and also the hierarchy(if available).

From the database normalization perspective, it is information that I need. Is there any documentation that I am missing out on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are thousands of objects to detect, and their list is not available publicly.

That being said, the image categories are available publicly in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-categorizing-images)

> Computer vision can categorize an image broadly or specifically, using
>   the list of 86 categories in the following diagram.
>
> [image: 86-category concept]

If you generally need a list of objects to use then you can use publicly available object datasets including the following (arranged from oldest to newest):

- COIL100
- SFU
- SOIL-47
- ETHZ Toys
- NORB
- CalTech 101
- PASCAL VOC
- GRAZ-02
- ALOI
- LabelME
- Tiny
- CIFAR10 and CIFAR100
- ImageNet
- BOSS
- Office
- BigBIRD
- MS-COCO
- iLab-20M
- CURE-OR

However, it is recommended to normalize your database based on the JSON you receive from the API, for example, you already know that you are going to receive `objects` when trying to use **Detect Objects**, and `categories` when trying to use **Analyze Image**, then you can work with that!